# JQuery Draggable Multiple Items with the same id not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable

Do you need to give each draggable element a different name? I have 3 images I want to be able to drag them around. I tried to give them all the same id but it fails. I will have a variable number of images so I need them all to have the same id. What is going wrong here?

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<style>
#draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; border:1px solid black;}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#draggable").draggable();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="draggable" src="small/Koala.jpg"/>
<img id="draggable" src="small/Desert.jpg"/>
<img id="draggable" src="small/Tulips.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Now it will not clone - I want to clone the image and drop the clone into the droppable box.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Wall Builder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <style>
        .draggable { width: 85px; height: 85px; padding: 0.5em; border:1px solid black;}
        .droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; border:1px solid black;}
        </style>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".draggable").draggable({
        revert: "invalid"
       ,helper: 'clone'
      });
      $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
        accept: "draggable"
      });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<img class="draggable" id="1" src="small/Koala.jpg"/>
<img class="draggable" id="2" src="small/Desert.jpg"/>
<img class="draggable" id="3" src="small/Tulips.jpg"/>
<div class="droppable" id="d1"></div>
<div class="droppable" id="d2"></div>
<div class="droppable" id="d3"></div>
<div class="droppable" id="d4"></div>
<div class="droppable" id="d5"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give them different ids and then select by class. The point of an id is to be distinct, and if there are duplicates jQuery will just select the first one it finds.

Something like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".draggable").draggable();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img class="draggable" src="small/Koala.jpg"/>
<img class="draggable" src="small/Desert.jpg"/>
<img class="draggable" src="small/Tulips.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

(sounds like you might want to read up on [the difference between ids and classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp))

Comment: Okay, thank you! If I want to clone, do I need an id for all of the droppable elements too?

Comment: That question is a little vague, so I'm not sure how to answer... In general: whatever you select and say `.clone()` on will be cloned, so if you only want to clone one thing only select one thing (either by giving something relevant an id and selecting by that, or selecting by the class and doing array indexing, or :first or something like that). Sounds like you might also need to read up on jquery selectors (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Comment: It will not clone. I have no idea why.

Comment: "it" is super vague. More info, please.

Comment: I added my code. I want to drag the clone into the droppable box. My goal is to also be able to move them around after they are snapped into place. Sorting is not necessary just no overlapping and they must be snapped into the drop box.

Comment: I'm gonna need to see a jsfiddle or some other kind of demo, I think.