# jquery draggable prevent overlap

Tags: jquery, jquery-draggable

I am creating a website, where two div should not overlap each other when dragging them.I have created a [jsFiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/chetanmani/dj8hn1zj/1/)

also the following is the code

```
$(".butNotHere").draggable({
    obstacle: ".butNotHere",
    preventCollision: true,
    containment: "#moveInHere"
});
```

I want to have the same class name for both the div
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with sort of a "hack" to deal with this. The issue here is the dragged div is its own obstacle (all share same class). So what I did is remove the class "" when the dragging starts and re-add it when it stops. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj8hn1zj/2/)

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    obstacle:".butNotHere",
    preventCollision: true,
    containment: "#moveInHere",
    start: function(event,ui) {
        $(this).removeClass('butNotHere');
    },
    stop: function(event,ui) {
        $(this).addClass('butNotHere');
    }
});
```